# Using @HiltAndroidApp on Parent Application and Child Application

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Let's say I have

```
// this class lives in the release (variant) directory
@HiltAndroidApp
open class MyParentApplication : Application() {
// some injection here
}

// this class lives in the debug (variant) directory 
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyChildApplication : MyParentApplication {
// some debug only injection here. Debug injections won't be available as part of any app releases
// use debug only injections to do debug only actions
}
```

When I tried to do the above, I will get some Dagger `error: cannot find symbol` related errors. However, when I removed `@HiltAndroidApp` from `MyParentApplication`, then everything compiles fine. Obviously, I can't do this because Dagger injection wouldn't work on the release build. What would be the appropriate Hilt setup to get a derived/child class injected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have two child `Applications`. One for `debug` and one for the `release`.

---

- parent `Application` in `src/main/your/package/` (no `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation)

```
open class ParentApplication : Application() {
// some injection here
}
```

- **release:** in `src/release/your/package/`

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ReleaseChildApplication : ParentApplication() {
// some injection can also be here, but does not have to...
}
```

- **debug:** in `src/debug/your/package/`

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class DebugChildApplication : ParentApplication() {
// debug injections here
}
```